# How to overflow views to the next row, instead of disappearing into the unknown

Tags: android, layout, textview

I am trying to fit TextViews in the screen, so that every textview contains 1 word of a long sentence.

This is a very long sentence, so long that it does not
fit in the screen.

Here `fit in the screen` are 4 textviews, which I need to move to the next line. Basically, this way I can get click events for each word (since I need to support Android 2.2, and Spannable needs getX and getY that 2.2 does not support).

Layout

```
         <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/word1"
                style="@style/select_part_of_speech_word" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/word2"
                style="@style/select_part_of_speech_word" />
..... more TextViews.....
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/word15"
                style="@style/select_part_of_speech_word" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Style applied

```
<style name="select_part_of_speech_word" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:text">@string/randomTutorialText</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">25sp</item>
    <item name="android:visibility">visible</item>
    <item name="android:lines">1</item>
</style>
```

With this, the textviews just seem to disappear. I guess if I use a horizontal scrollview, I will be able to view all 15 textviews, but I need them to overflow to the next available space below. Can this be done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want something equivalent to a FlowLayout.

You could try Romain Guy's [implementation](http://code.google.com/p/devoxx-schedule/source/browse/devoxx-android-client/src/net/peterkuterna/android/apps/devoxxsched/ui/widget/FlowLayout.java?name=422c381967&r=422c38196733ba3c54eb44418160e248ee1aea86).